# scooter won't restart after shutting off

Tags: starting, scooter

I have a VIP Future Champion which I ride on a daily basis. I can jump it and it will start. But as soon as I shut it off it won't restart. I've tried to kick start it but there seems to be no compression. It has a new battery. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: I would bet the power leads are not connected properly since you have a new battery.

Comment: Did you have to fill the battery with acid when you purchased it or did the shop do that for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try to unplug your spark plug and then kick start it.
Watch the tip of the spark plug, if it doesn't make any spark try to replace this spark plug.

Comment: I tried to kick start it. I can't for some reason. Don't know if its because I'm only 100 obs or if its just super tight. I did take the terminals off the battery and gave them a good scouring with a Brillo pad and got some of the rust off. Which is strange since the battery is only a few months old. Have it on the charger to recondition now. It did fire back up. Thanks for the tips. Turns out I could use a new spark plug. Looks a little burnt